# Pyspark: Serialized task exceeds max allowed. Consider increasing spark.rpc.message.maxSize or using broadcast variables for large values

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, message, rpc, max-size

I'm doing calculations on a cluster and at the end when I ask summary statistics on my Spark dataframe with df.describe().show() I get an error:

Serialized task 15:0 was 137500581 bytes, which exceeds max allowed: spark.rpc.message.maxSize (134217728 bytes). Consider increasing spark.rpc.message.maxSize or using broadcast variables for large values

In my Spark configuration I already tried to increase the aforementioned parameter:

```
spark = (SparkSession
         .builder
         .appName("TV segmentation - dataprep for scoring")
         .config("spark.executor.memory", "25G")
         .config("spark.driver.memory", "40G")
         .config("spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled", "true")
         .config("spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors", "12")
         .config("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "3g")
         .config("spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max.mb", "2047mb")
         .config("spark.rpc.message.maxSize", "1000mb")
         .getOrCreate())
```

I also tried to repartition my dataframe using:

```py
dfscoring=dfscoring.repartition(100)
```

but still I keep on getting the same error.

My environment: Python 3.5, Anaconda 5.0, Spark 2

How can I avoid this error ?

Comment: how did you create df? from reading file or python objects?

Answer (score 17):

i'm in same trouble, then i solve it. 
the cause is `spark.rpc.message.maxSize` if default set `128M`, you can change it when launch a spark client, i'm work in pyspark and set the value to 1024, so i write like this:

```
pyspark --master yarn --conf spark.rpc.message.maxSize=1024
```

solve it.

Comment: Thanks for the solution @libin but what units are the standard for spark.rpc.message.maxSize property? MiB, MB, Bytes? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Hi, @GeorgeFandango, I am glad to help you, the unit of this configuration is MiB. And the detailed documents are here, please pay attention to your spark version: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#application-properties

Comment: This is the detailed description of the configuration item `spark.rpc.message.maxSize`:  


 Maximum message size (in MiB) to allow in "control plane" communication; generally only applies to map output size information sent between executors and the driver. Increase this if you are running jobs with many thousands of map and reduce tasks and see messages about the RPC message size.

Comment: Thanks a lot @libin! Now my process is working properly :)

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue and it wasted a day of my life that I am never getting back. I am not sure why this is happening, but here is how I made it work for me.

**Step 1: Make sure that PYSPARK_PYTHON and PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON are correctly set.**
Turned out that python in worker(2.6) had a different version than in driver(3.6). You should check if environment variables PYSPARK_PYTHON and PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON are correctly set.

I fixed it by simply switching my kernel from Python 3 Spark 2.2.0 to Python Spark 2.3.1 in Jupyter. You may have to set it up manually. Here is how to make sure your PySpark is set up correctly https://mortada.net/3-easy-steps-to-set-up-pyspark.html

**STEP 2: If that doesn't work, try working around it:**
This kernel switch worked for DFs that I haven't added any columns to:
spark_df -> panda_df -> back_to_spark_df .... but it didn't work on the DFs where I had added 5 extra columns. **So what I tried and it worked was the following:**

```
# 1. Select only the new columns: 

    df_write = df[['hotel_id','neg_prob','prob','ipw','auc','brier_score']]


# 2. Convert this DF into Spark DF:



     df_to_spark = spark.createDataFrame(df_write)
     df_to_spark = df_to_spark.repartition(100)
     df_to_spark.registerTempTable('df_to_spark')


# 3. Join it to the rest of your data:

    final = df_to_spark.join(data,'hotel_id')


# 4. Then write the final DF. 

    final.write.saveAsTable('schema_name.table_name',mode='overwrite')
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 5):

I had faced the same issue while converting the sparkDF to pandasDF.
I am working on Azure-Databricks , first you need to check the memory set in the spark config using below -

```
spark.conf.get("spark.rpc.message.maxSize")
```

Then we can increase the memory-

```
spark.conf.set("spark.rpc.message.maxSize", "500")
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem but using Watson studio. My solution was:

```
sc.stop()
configura=SparkConf().set('spark.rpc.message.maxSize','256')
sc=SparkContext.getOrCreate(conf=configura)
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
```

I hope it help someone...

Comment: It helped me a lot! Thank you! This solution saved me.

Answer (score 1):

For those folks, who are looking for AWS Glue script pyspark based way of doing this. The below code snippet might be useful

```
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark import SparkConf
myconfig=SparkConf().set('spark.rpc.message.maxSize','256') 
#SparkConf can be directly used with its .set  property
sc = SparkContext(conf=myconfig)

glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
..
..
```

Answer (score 0):

AWS Glue notebook solution:
Run this cell magic before creating the spark and glue contexts. For me this is the only working way to set spark.rpc.message.maxSize in AWS Glue 4.0, as of March 2024.

```
%%configure -f
{
"conf": "spark.rpc.message.maxSize=512"
}
```