# pyspark change big pandas dataframe to pyspark dataframe and write to s3 got error

Tags: pyspark

Spark version>2.
While trying to change a large pandas dataframe to spark dataframe and write to s3, got error:

```
Serialized task 880:0 was 665971191 bytes, which exceeds max allowed: spark.rpc.message.maxSize (134217728 bytes). Consider increasing spark.rpc.message.maxSize or using broadcast variables for large values.
```

Tried to do a repartition to increase partition and it did not solve the problem.

Read through this
[Pyspark: Serialized task exceeds max allowed. Consider increasing spark.rpc.message.maxSize or using broadcast variables for large values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54458815/pyspark-serialized-task-exceeds-max-allowed-consider-increasing-spark-rpc-mess)

tried following:

```
from pyspark.conf import SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession


spark = (SparkSession.builder
        .master("yarn")
        .appName("myWork") 
        .config("spark.rpc.message.maxSize", "1024mb")
        .getOrCreate())
```

Still got the problem.
Any suggestion?